# De-serializing many to many field with a through table in DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, serialization

I am working on developing a Trello-like website with Django Rest Framework.
I want to add selected users to `BoardAccess` model, a through table for `User` model and `Board` model, two of which are in Many to Many relationship. Being added to `BoardAccess` table will mean that the respective users will be having access to matching boards.

**Models.py**

```
class Board(models.Model):
    name           = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    access_granted = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='BoardAccess', related_name='access_boards')
    team           = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE) # a team can have many boards


class BoardAccess(models.Model):
    user    = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    board   = models.ForeignKey('Board', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

For User, I am currently using Django's default Auth User model and extending it with a Profile model via OneToOne Field.

**Serializers.py**

```
class BoardAccessSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    members = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    added_users = # ???
    new_name = serializers.CharField(
        write_only=True, required=False, source='name') # in case of requests for renaming the board

    def get_members(self, instance):
        members = User.objects.filter(profile__team=instance.team)
        return UserBoardSerializer(members, many=True).data
```

**I would like to know what field / relations / another serializer should be assigned to `added_users`, which I think should be `write_only=True`, in order to successfully de-serialize input from the client-side containing primary keys of selected users.**

`get_members()` method is used to first display information of all team members, from which a client will select users to be added to the board.

**Views.py**

```
class BoardAccessRetrieveUpdateAPIView(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = BoardAccessSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get_queryset(self):
        team_id = self.kwargs.get('team_id')
        team = get_object_or_404(Team, id=team_id)
        queryset = Board.objects.select_related(
            'team').prefetch_related(
            'access_granted').filter(team=team)
        return queryset
```

I am new to DRF, so there may be a lot of points to be improved from the above. I would really appreciate every help!!

Answer (score 0):

You can override the update method in your serializer, and get the user ids from the client side from initial_data

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    // do the actions on create
    users = self.initial_data.get('users')
    instance.access_granted.add(*users)
    instance.save()
    return instance
```

Also when using ModelSerializer have to add Meta class:

```
 class BoardAccessSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

     class Meta:
           model = Board
           fields = "__all__"
```